# Scala / specs2 : could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type AsExecution[ExecutionEnv => MatchResult[Future[AuthenticationResult]]]

Tags: scala, playframework, implicit, specs2

I am trying to upgrade a Scala/Play application to `Play 2.7`, `Scala 2.12.11`.

I have the following test that probably used to work before I upgraded Play and Scala.

After the upgrade, I got the following compilation error:

`Error: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type org.specs2.specification.core.AsExecution[org.specs2.concurrent.ExecutionEnv => org.specs2.matcher.MatchResult[scala.concurrent.Future[services.AuthenticationResult]]]`

```
import org.specs2.concurrent.ExecutionEnv
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification

import scala.concurrent.duration._

class AuthenticationServiceSpec extends Specification {

  "The AuthenticationService" should {

    val service: AuthenticationService = new MyAuthenticationService

    "correctly authenticate Me" in { implicit ee: ExecutionEnv =>
      service.authenticateUser("myname", "mypassowrd") must beEqualTo (AuthenticationSuccessful).await(1, 200.millis)
    }

  }

}
```

To try to solve the compilation error, I added an implicit parameter to the class constructor (BTW, how did it work before, without an implicit parameter?):

```
import org.specs2.concurrent.ExecutionEnv
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification

import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.Future

import org.specs2.specification.core.AsExecution
import org.specs2.matcher.MatchResult    

class AuthenticationServiceSpec(implicit ee: AsExecution[ExecutionEnv => MatchResult[Future[AuthenticationResult]]]) extends Specification {

  "The AuthenticationService" should {

    val service: AuthenticationService = new MyAuthenticationService

    "correctly authenticate Me" in { implicit ee: ExecutionEnv =>
      service.authenticateUser("myname", "mypassowrd") must beEqualTo (AuthenticationSuccessful).await(1, 200.millis)
    }

  }

}
```

However in runtime when I run the test, I am getting the error:

`Can't find a suitable constructor with 0 or 1 parameter for class org.specs2.specification.core.AsExecution`

Based on the constructor of `AsExecution`, it makes sense...

How can I solve this problem then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
class AuthenticationServiceSpec(implicit ee: ExecutionEnv) extends Specification {

  "The AuthenticationService" should {

    val service: AuthenticationService = new MyAuthenticationService

    "correctly authenticate Me" in {
      service.authenticateUser("myname", "mypassword") must beEqualTo (AuthenticationSuccessful).await(1, 200.millis)
    }

  }

}
```

The `ee: ExecutionEnv` will be injected directly in the specification when it is built.

That's the meaning of the message `Can't find a suitable constructor with 0 or 1 parameter for class ...`. `specs2` tries to recursively build arguments for a specification if they have a constructor with 0 or 1 argument. The `ExecutionEnv` is such an argument that `specs2` is able to build on its own.

Comment: Thanks :) I think the method parameter should be implicit. What did the original `AsExecution[ExecutionEnv => MatchResult[Future[AuthenticationResult]]]` try to do? `AsExecution` has two implicit methods (`resultAsExecution`, `futureAsExecution`) that I wonder how they can be useful. How did the original code work without an implicit parameter?

Comment: The original code with `implicit ee: ExecutionEnv => ` at the example level worked because specs2 had a conversion from `ExecutionEnv => R` where `R : AsResult` to an `Execution` (because eventually a specification only a stream of `Fragment = (Description, Execution)`. I eventually moved the providing of an `ExecutionEnv` as a kind of dependency injection at the level of the specification to cut back on the duplication for each example (and also as way to inject other data if necessary). Yes the `ee` parameter needs to be implicit, I fixed the answer.